# mixed numbers programming not working

Tags: python

```
def main():
num = int(input("Enter the Numerator:"))
den = int(input("Enter the Denominator:"))

whole_num = num // den
fract_num = num % den

print('The mixed number is {} and {}/{}', format (whole_num, fract_num,den)) 
main ()
```

This is currently how I have my program written, so that when a person enters 23 as the numerator and 6 as the denominator is prints out the solution as a mixed number. But when I run my code it is still coming back with an error. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: What error?  Please provide the traceback.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.

Comment: You typed `,` instead of `.` between the string and the `format`. If your code does not run, the first step in fixing it is to proofread it to make sure you didn't make a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that the built-in function [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format) is different from [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)**.

You might encounter the issue `TypeError: format() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`, which is caused by

```
print('The mixed number is {} and {}/{}', format(whole_num, fract_num,den))
```

To fix it, replace the line with,

```
print('The mixed number is {} and {}/{}'.format(whole_num, fract_num,den))
```

---

The full source code, (pay attention to the code indentation)

```
def main():
    num = int(input("Enter the Numerator:"))
    den = int(input("Enter the Denominator:"))

    whole_num = num // den
    fract_num = num % den

    print('The mixed number is {} and {}/{}'.format (whole_num, fract_num, den)) 

main()

# Demo
$ python3 test.py 
Enter the Numerator:23
Enter the Denominator:6
The mixed number is 3 and 5/6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the comma to a dot as follows.

```
print('The mixed number is {} and {}/{}'.format(whole_num, fract_num,den))
```